# why cant i download/install software (supported in windows) in linux operating system ubuntu

Tags: unity

1. Why cant I download/install software (supported in windows) in linux operating system ubuntu?
2. How to install software from internet?
3. How to install youwave/bluestacks/or any android os in linux os ubuntu?
4. How to install whatsapp on ubuntu?
5. why  can't I download applications/apps from any internet website?
6. I can't get any useful software such as android os/playback audio devices etc., in "ubuntu softwaren center?
7. are there any inbuilt software in ubuntu?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. You can, but you have to realise that Ubuntu is very different from Windows.
   Therefore you cannot run applications designed for Windows directly on Ubuntu. **Wine** is a Windows emulator in Linux which can help you run some Windows applications on Ubuntu.
2. Download software designed for Linux and follow the install instructions.
   Look especially for .deb-files, they can be installed via the Software Central.
3. See 6
4. Available through your browser, look here: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/whatsapp-now-available-to-use-in-linux-through-web-browser
5. You can, but the application has to be for Linux.
6. There is a lot of useful software but it (often) not the same that you might be use to from Windows. There is Android emulators for Linux if that is what you are after. **Genymotion** for example.
7. Yes. And the addons of your choice are available through the Software Center.